# Can you push codes from one branch to another, a different downstream to a different upstream

Tags: git, gitlab

I am working on a different branch in my local machine, but I want to push the codes to a different branch upstream. How can this be done. I am trying to push to nicholas-dev
This is the error message I am getting

```
C:\Users\njoca\Documents\BoTest\boegisexternal (dev-samuel -> origin)
λ git push nicholas-dev
fatal: 'nicholas-dev' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
git push origin dev-samuel:nicholas-dev
```

where `origin` is the name of the remote, `dev-samuel` the name of the local branch, and `nicholas-dev` the name of the branch on the remote.

Comment: Thanks, It is showing I pushed the codes to the branch, but I cannot see my commit or codes on the branch

Comment: @Joca Impossible to say really what's happening with that info.